# Scroll-bar cover on inner-container

Tags: html, css

The container is an popup, so it must be block and absolute. It has a max-height and it can contain a table as my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3rsaLcwe

```
.container
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If table's height > it's height, only vertical scroll-bar is appeared but we must hide horizontal scroll-bar. However, the vertical-scroll-bar cover on table. Please help me to fix this problem. Note that the table's width is dynamic, horizontal scroll-bar must be hidden and vertical scroll-bar not cover on table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you mean, the scrollbar covers the table.
just add a padding to the container:

```
padding-right:10px;
```

Comment: UI will be not good when table's height < 300. Padding is remaining space.

Comment: You can add it via code...
var height = $(".container").height(); 
if (height > 300) {
    $('.container').css('padding-right','10px');
}

Comment: We don't have solution by using CSS?

Comment: I fixed it by Javascript. Thanks.